# When I try to use the string parameter for ComSourceInterfaces instead of typeof I cannot register the assembly as a COM object

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

When I try to use the string parameter for ComSourceInterfaces instead of typeof I cannot register the assembly as a COM object.  I'm implementing multiple interfaces because that is what is required by the SDK.

When I use

```
[ComVisible(true),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
ComSourceInterfaces("IAccessControl"),
Guid("738CFFEF-37DC-4C61-957E-C5A78FE20223")]
public class EventGeneratorV2  : IAccessControl
```

I get the error

> error MSB3217: Cannot register assembly "...\Event Generator v2.dll". Could not load type 'IAccessControl' from assembly 'Event
>   Generator v2, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=bffdb712704a75b7'.

However if I change my code to use

```
[ComVisible(true),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IAccessControl)),
Guid("738CFFEF-37DC-4C61-957E-C5A78FE20223")]
public class EventGeneratorV2  : IAccessControl
```

It does work correctly.  I also tried the full qualified name for the IAccessControl interface, Lib.Interfaces.IAcccessControl as the string but it still fails.  The best resolution would be to use multiple ComSourceInterfaces but you can only use that once and it takes at most 4 interfaces using typeof.  I have 9 interfaces I need to implement in order for it to be compatible with this other software.  Is there a way to get the string to work?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.  The string is actually "Lib.Interfaces.IAcccessControl, Lib" for each Interface.  Where the first part is the fully qualified name for the interface and the lib is the Reference that that the Interface is coming from.

Then when I add the other interfaces I have to add the \0 between each.  So my final ComSourceInterfaces is the rather lengthy

```
ComSourceInterfaces("Lib.Interfaces.IAccessControl, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IAccessControl2, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.ITranslate, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.ITranslate2, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IComConfig, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IComConfig2, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IInput, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IInput2, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IAsset, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IAsset2, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IFakeName, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IComManager, Lib\0Lib.Interfaces.IDistributeEvent, Lib")
```

After that the DLL compiles and registers correctly.